# Why is this one says undefined?

Tags: javascript, html

```
<section id="clickme">
     <p>Stuff goes here.</p>
</section>


$("#clickme").on("click", function(){
    alert(this.innerHTML);
    setTimeout(function(){
                alert(this.innerHTML);
    }, 1000);
})
```

Does anyone know why the second alert is undefined?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The context changes within the inner function. If you want to use the target within it, you need to set a var equal to `this` prior to it, like this:

```
$("#clickme").on("click", function(){
    alert(this.innerHTML);
    var that = this;
    setTimeout(function(){
                alert(that.innerHTML);
    }, 1000);
})
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/5CXVS/)

Comment: But why it gave me an undefined result?

Comment: @PenghanYang: Because inside the `setTimeout` handler, `this` is `window` (because `setTimeout` is actually `window.setTimeout`); so `this.innerHTML` is `window.innerHTML`, which is not what you want.

Comment: @PenghanYang, here are good references for you to learn more about javascript contexts. [Understanding Javascript Context](http://joshuakehn.com/2011/10/20/Understanding-JavaScript-Context.html) and [Javascript this different contexts](http://www.impressivewebs.com/javascript-this-different-contexts/)

Comment: Thank you! Thank you so much for providing me with those references. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

`this` changes. You can avoid it simply by proxying `this` (preserving it somewhere else):

```
var that = this;
setTimeout(function(){
            alert(that.innerHTML);
}, 1000);
```

or by using `bind` (which effectively does the same thing).

Answer (score 2):

As what @jaeheung answered:

> setTimeout() is a method of Window object. And the 'this' points to Window which doesn't have innerHTML.

Just create a variable to store the object in so there is no conflict.

```
$("#clickme").on("click", function(){
    var myObj = this;
    alert(myObj.innerHTML);
    setTimeout(function(){
                alert(myObj.innerHTML);
    }, 1000);
})
```

Answer (score 0):

setTimeout() is a method of Window object. And the 'this' points to Window which doesn't have innerHTML.

Comment: Thank you very much! Could you please explain on it a little bit more? I'm a noob on it...

Comment: Your "setTimeout(function(){..." is actually an abbreviation of "window.setTimeout(function(){...". And the function is registered as a event handler of window object. When the event is triggered, it has nothing to do with your "#clickme" object, but it's the window object that actually executes the code in the function. So the 'this' has to point to the window object.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is equivalent to:

```
$("#clickme").on("click", function(){
    alert(this.innerHTML);             // `this` points to the event object (`section`)
    window.setTimeout(function(){      // notice the 'window.'
                alert(this.innerHTML); // `this` now points to `window`
    }, 1000);
})
```

The `undefined` error is coming because `this.innerHTML` translates to `window.innerHTML` because the internal `this` points to `window`.  The `window` object does not have an `innerHTML` attribute, so it results in an `undefined` property.

In order to use the `section` element object, you need to cache it in a variable somewhere:

```
$("#clickme").on("click", function(){
    var _this = this;                  // cached
    alert(_this.innerHTML);            // use cached
    setTimeout(function(){
       alert(_this.innerHTML);         // use cached
    }, 1000);
})
```

Alternatively, a method that I'm not sure will work in IE is to pass it as an argument to `setTimeout`:

```
$("#clickme").on("click", function(){
    alert(this.innerHTML);              // `this` points to the event object (`section`)
    setTimeout(function(_this){         // notice the `_this` as a parameter
                alert(_this.innerHTML); // `_this` now points to the argument
    }, 1000, this);                     // pass it here
})
```